# Return an empty array if string == ""

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

I'm rewriting my old table sort library. In the library, I have this method which gets some attributes from the table:

```
<table data-sort-cols="" data-sort-orders="">
```

```
getSortInfo : function(element) {
    switch (element.tagName) {
        case "TABLE":
            function getSortAttr(element, attr) {
                var info = element.getAttribute(attr);
                if (info != "") {
                    info = info.split(",").map(function(val) { return parseInt(val,10) });
                } else {
                    info = [];
                }
                return info;
            };
            return {
                columns : getSortAttr(element, "data-sort-cols"),
                orders  : getSortAttr(element, "data-sort-orders"),
            }
```

I want to shorten the `getSortAttr` function. Function returns the assigned value (e.g. "1,3,2" -> [1,3,2]). If there is not an assigned value to the attribute, it returns an empty array. I want to get rid of the if statement.

Is there a way to modify this line, and make it return an empty array if the string is empty `""`?

```
info = info.split(",").map(function(val) { return parseInt(val,10) });
```

I've tried

```
// returns [NaN]
"".split(",").map(function(val) {
    return parseInt(val, 10);
})

// returns [undefined]
"".split(",").map(function(val) {
    var num = parseInt(val, 10);
    if (!isNaN(num) && isFinite(num)) {
        return num;
    }
})
```

but didn't work.

Comment: Til ES6, that function declaration is invalid in that position. Better move it outside of the `switch` statement.

Comment: Originally, it's outside the switch statement, declared as another method of the main object. Testing things atm. Thanks for the notice though.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the `if` statement? Checking the input once before the map seems better than using a filter as in the accepted answer, since that unnecessarily checks all the elements of the array.

Comment: @Barmar `data-sort-x` attributes are set at the initialization stage and `getSortInfo` method is called when the user clicks on a column header. `data-sort-x` is set to empty strings before any sorting; after a sort, it changes to "2,1" (column indexes or orders). If statement required for the first sorting. After that I thought it is redundant ... Though I'm not sure if what I'm looking for is a good practice.

Comment: The answer you accepted performs the test on every sort. It just tests in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
function getSortAttr(element, attr) {
   return (element.getAttribute(attr) || "").split(",").filter(Boolean).map(Number);
}
```

to filter out empty strings from the array before mapping them to numbers.

Comment: This seems to do the job. I've omitted the `||` part and used `element.getAttribute(attr).split(",").filter(Boolean).map(Number)`, because the attribute is already set to an empty string before any function call. It's dynamically modifed later.

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure whether the attributes always existed. Better be safe than sorry :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following function will check `if info == ""`, if info == "", it will then return an empty array, if not, it will split the info string and map it. This is called a `shorthand` if statement.

```
info = (info == "") ? [] : info.split(",").map(function(val) { return parseInt(val,10) });
```

You can also add more conditions to the shorthand condition, e.g:

```
(info == "" || info != undefined || info != null)
```

If the above `info == ""` doesn't work, this might mean that `info` is *undefined*. To combat this we can use the following statement:

```
(typeof(info) != undefined)
```